# Application Scope Resources in Glassfish3.1 Console

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

As you know in Glassfish v3.1 we can have scope resources instead of global resources. I want to view/check our application resources with Glassfish Console panel, it seems Console panel just list Global resources (in Resources > JDBC > Datasources or Connection Pools)

How can I view the application-scope resource inside the console panel for a deployed app or module?

RGDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GlassFish Server 3.1.2 has added the ability to view application-scoped resources using the administration console.  Check out [The Aquarium blog entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/final_rc_5_for_glassfish) on how to download GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 Release Candidate 5.

Hope this helps.